# Hibernate doesn't save entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm really new to hibernate and try to understand how it works. But know I faced with the problem.

First of all, I have such mapping:

```java
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Author() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

But then, when I tried to save this entitye with `session.save()`, hibernate showed me error like

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "author" violates not-null constraint
 Failing row contains (null, hello!).
```

So I decided to notice, why hibernate doesn't increment the id automaticy and recognized that POSTGRESQL doesn't suppert annotation `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. So I changet it to the `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. The error was gone, but entity wasn't saved.

So here's **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate?useSSL=false
      &amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">4122</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="hibernate.entity.Author"/>
    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here's **HibernateUtil.java**

```java
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder()
                .build();
        SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder();
        return sessionFactoryBuilder.build();
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And here's the **Main.java**, where I call the hibernate functions:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Author author = new Author();
            author.setName("hello!");
            session.save(author);
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println(session.get(Author.class, 1L));
        }
    }
}
```

After program execution it prints me null and there is no entity in database:

[image]

If you know, what can be the problem, please tell me. I'd really apreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is setter for id missing:

```
public long setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Oh, really, it was kinda stupid. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Cross, it just happens:). Btw, usually automatic generation is used for this (with IDE or Lombok)